# porting java code to javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I have a Java class constructor, part of which allows me to set the variable 'key' on instantiation:

```
public class Note
{
    private int key;

    public Note()
    {
        setKey(1 + (int)(Math.random() * 13D));
    }

    public void setKey(int i)
    {
        key = (i > 0) & (i <= 13) ? i : 0;
    }
}
```

I would like to rewrite the code in javascript so that I can use it on a webpage without the java runtime environment.  I tried:

```
var Note = function() {
    pitch : setKey( Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1); 
}

function setKey(i) {
    var key = (i > 0) & (i <= 13) ? i : 0;
    console.log("Here key is: " + key); // prints a number
    return key;
}

var note1 = new Note(); 
console.log( note1.pitch); // THIS PRINTS UNDEFINED
```

What am I failing to understand about initialising the variable 'pitch'?

Thanks very much for any help.
Gerard

Comment: becuase that is a label inside the function, not a property.

Comment: That's a label, not a property... you are in a function, not an object... `this.pitch = setKey(...)`

Comment: I'll have to do a lot more study of javascript objects. The label looks just like this (from MDN's Working With Objects):                                                var obj = { property_1:   value_1,   // property_# may be an identifier...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), not a property.

```js
var Note = function() {
    this.pitch = setKey( Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1); 
};

function setKey(i) {
    var key = (i > 0) & (i <= 13) ? i : 0;
    console.log("Here key is: " + key); // prints a number
    return key;
}

var note1 = new Note(); 
console.log( note1.pitch); // THIS PRINTS UNDEFINED
```

Answer (score 0):

How you would do POO without using ES6 features:

```js
function Note() {
    // constructor
    this.pitch = this.setKey(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1);
}
    
Note.prototype.setKey = function(i) {
    return (i > 0) & (i <= 13) ? i : 0;
}
    
var note = new Note();
console.log(note.pitch);
```

If you want to use ES6 features (for example using a pre-compiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io)):

```js
class Note {
    constructor() {
        this.pitch = this.setKey(Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1);
    }
    
    setKey(i) {
        return (i > 0) & (i <= 13) ? i : 0;
    }
}

let note = new Note();
console.log(note.pitch);
```